# Laravel 4 - Repository Interface not found

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-4, interface, repository-pattern

Just started working through laracasts and trying to move on from direct eloquent use in the controllers.

I have implemented everything that I need to but hitting this error:

```
Class tva\Repositories\VehicleRepositoryInterface does not exist
```

My folder structure is:

```
app/
  tva/
    repositories/
```

VehiclesController:

```
use tva\Repositories\VehicleRepositoryInterface;

class VehiclesController extends \BaseController {
  protected $vehicle;

  public function __construct(VehicleRepositoryInterface $vehicle)
  {
    $this->vehicle = $vehicle;
  }

}
```

In the repositories folder:

VehicleRepository:

```
namespace tva\Repositories;

class VehicleRepository implements VehicleRepositoryInterface {
}
```

VehicleRepositoryInterface:

```
namespace tva\Repositories;

interface VehicleRepositoryInterface {
}
```

And also updated my composer.json:

```
"psr-0": {
  "tva": "app/"
},
```

To me, this should work?

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved, instead of using psr-0 I added the directory to the classmap and all issues solved.